# Complete installation guide for NIST Biometric Image Software (NBIS)?

Tags: installation, fingerprint, biometrics

When trying to install NBIS I get the following error on linux, when running `./setup.sh`:

```
zsh: permission denied: ./setup.sh
```

and the following when running `make config`:

```
/bin/sh: 3: ./configure: Permission denied
/home/...../Downloads/Rel_5.0.0/buildutil/png_libs.mak:54: recipe for target 'config' failed
make[3]: *** [config] Error 1
```

I used ARK to extract the zip file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [unzip](https://askubuntu.com/q/86849/214597) utility to extract the .zip file containing the NBIS source. `unzip` maintains the file permission structure of the zip file contents. Then you can install as per normal.

## Install guide

```sh
unzip nbis_v5_0_0.zip
cd Rel_5.0.0

sudo mkdir /usr/local/NBIS/Main
# Ensure a absolute path is provided to setup.sh
./setup.sh /usr/local/NBIS/Main --64 #or --32 if you have a 32 bit system
make config
make it
sudo make install LIBNBIS=yes

cd ..
rm -r -f Rel_5.0.0
```

## I don't have access to the zip/can't use unzip

You can change the permissions of the relevant files with:

```sh
chmod ug+x ./setup.sh
chmod ug+x ./png/src/lib/png/configure
chmod ug+x ./png/src/lib/zlib/configure
```

Then you can install as per normal.

Answer (score 1):

I installed first gcc and x11 library in order to avoid error:

1. A gcc library

   sudo  apt-get install cmake libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 g++-multilib
2. X11 library

   sudo apt-get install libx11-dev

Then I unzip nbis_v5_0_0

```
cd Rel_5.0.0
./setup.sh /path_to_run --64 (or --32)
sudo make config
sudo make it
sudo install LIBNBIS=yes
```